Is there a way to render a menù on server side and hide it by using a button on client component on nextjs 14 with app router?
I am rendering a menù on server side, like:
    //this is on server
    import Link from 'next/link';
    function Page() {
     return(<nav>
      <Link href="/">Home</Link>
     </nav>
    }

In this case a need a button to show or hide the content, i know i can use 'use client' but i don't want this because googlebot need to crawl static menù. I looked many solutions but nothing works for me. It is comical for advanced framework such nextjs 14.
i tried many solutions but i need something works for what i specified on the title.

Fixed by using  after that i retrieve the elemnt with document.getElementById. Classic way on javascript.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Adding use client doesn't block Next.js to render your component on server side. We still get that component inside the HTML of returned response of first URL.
If you still don't want to use it or if you have any server call inside of that component, you can create a wrapper client component like below and pass server component as children inside.
// App.jsx
function App() {
  return (
    <ClientMenuToggle>
      <ServerNavigationMenu />
    </ClientMenuToggle>
  );
}

// ClientMenuToggleWithButton.jsx
'use client';

export default function ClientMenuToggleWithButton({ children }) {
  // children is your  <ServerNavigationMenu /> component
 // add toggle logic
}

// ServerNavigationMenu.jsx
export default function ServerNavigationMenu() {
  // navigation menu
}

Also, for your own answer, retrieving element with document.getElementById in React is not recommended or needed.
